# How to determine what IIS module is executing to set preCondition?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, web-config

I have added Web API into Web Forms application.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition=""/>
  </modules>
```

I have some code in Global.asax.vb:

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires at the beginning of each request
End Sub
```

I don't want to create a separate module for it. This code works fine in IIS 7.5 (Windows 7) when I make requests to Web API. However, the event does not fire in IIS 7.0 (Windows Server 2008).

IIS 7 modules:
[image: IIS 7 modules]

I found that everything is good with runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true":

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition=""/>
  </modules>
```

However, I want to get rid of this parameter by explicitly setting `preCondition=""` for the specific HTTP module.

I don't know what module needs to be added. How to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by installing [KB980368](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368) hotfix.

My server has all actual Windows updates installed. I didn't think that the hotfix is required for me.

Comment: Thanks, this also solved our problem too. Spent hours looking at IIS and web site configuration differences between our Windows Server 2008 IIS 7 box and development Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5 box